# Show/Hide div on click and disappears after clicking outside the div

Tags: jquery

Will someone do to me so that after clicking outside the div - div disappeared? Because now it disappears only when you click `Click to Show / Hide div` again

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show').click(function() {
      $('.menu').toggle(1,"linear", "slide");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show">Click to Show/ Hide div</div>
 <div class="menu" style="display: none;">
    <ol>
      <li>India</li>
      <li>US</li>
      <li>UK</li>
      <li>Australia</li>
    </ol>
 </div>
```

Comment: `after clicking outside the div` - which `div` are you talking about (`#show` or `.menu`)?

Comment: .menu (the one that appears after clicking in #menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is your requirement.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show">Click to Show/ Hide div</div>
 <div class="menu" style="display: none;">
    <ol>
      <li>India</li>
      <li>US</li>
      <li>UK</li>
      <li>Australia</li>
    </ol>
 </div>


 $('#show').click(function() {

      $('.menu').toggle(1,"linear", "slide");

       //OR

      $('.menu').toggle();
    });
```

This will check your clicked element has no id=show

```
$(document).click(function(e) {

  if( e.target.id != 'show') {
    $(".menu").hide();
  }
});
```